# How to make a 404 page for a single view?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a function-based view that I want if I set the URL to show me a 404 page.

I know it can be set in the settings.py with DEBUG = True, but I have serious problems doing so.

Now I can make only this page be with Http404?

url.py

```
url(r'^reporte_servicio_externo/(?P<pk>[\w{}.-]{20})/$', 'apps.servicios.views.reporte_servicio_externo',
      name='reporte_servicio_externo')
```

view.py

```
def reporte_servicio_externo(request, pk):
    anuncio = Anuncio.objects.get(pk=get_unhash(pk))
    anuncioproyectos = AnuncioProyectos.objects.filter(anuncio=anuncio)
    cadena_tipo_carga = []
    cadena_actividad = []
    cadena_trafico = []
    cadena_escala = []
    cadena_ambito = []
    cadena_articulo = []
    cadena_tipo_producto = []
    cadena_muelles = []

    title_meta = 'Reporte Anuncio'
    title = 'Reporte Anuncio'

    if anuncio.tipo_carga:
        tipo_carga = anuncio.tipo_carga.all()
        for i in tipo_carga:
            cadena_tipo_carga.append(i.nombre)

    if anuncio.amarraderos:
        amarraderos = anuncio.amarraderos.all().values('nombre')
        for item in amarraderos:
            cadena_muelles.append(item['nombre'])

    for item in anuncioproyectos:
        if item.escala:
            cadena_escala.append(item.escala)

        if item.ambito:
            cadena_ambito.append(item.ambito.nombre)

        if item.articulo:
            cadena_articulo.append(item.articulo.nombre)

        if item.tipo_producto:
            cadena_tipo_producto.append(item.tipo_producto.nombre)

        for i in item.actividad.all():
            cadena_actividad.append(i.nombre)

        for i in item.tipo_trafico.all():
            cadena_trafico.append(i.nombre)

    cadena_tipo_carga = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_tipo_carga)))
    cadena_actividad = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_actividad)))
    cadena_trafico = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_trafico)))
    cadena_escala = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_escala)))
    cadena_ambito = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_ambito)))
    cadena_articulo = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_articulo)))
    cadena_tipo_producto = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_tipo_producto)))
    cadena_muelles = ", ".join(list(set(cadena_muelles)))

    return render('externo/ServicioExterno/reporte_servicio_externo.html', locals(), context_instance=ctx(request))
```

Try this example, but nothing. But I'm missing something, but I do not know what it is.

example django docs

````
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Poll

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})```
````

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Where do you want the 404 page? Why? What does that poll detail view have to do with anything? What does the DEBUG setting have to do with it either?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it the `detail()` view that doesn't do what you want? Why are you showing us a `reporte_servicio_externo()` view?

Comment: The ```detail ``` function is an example of the Django documents, my function is ```reporte_servicio_externo```

Comment: OK, but what are you trying to do with it? What isn't working? What is supposed to trigger a 404?

Comment: My report works normally, but now when the user changes the url for any one should leave a 404 error page. I tried the example of the documents provided by django, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to show a 404 if they hit that URL (and subsequently that view) and that object isn't there anymore. Sure, there's a way to do that. There is something called [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) that does exactly this. This is how you use it

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
anuncio = get_object_or_404(Anuncio, pk=get_unhash(pk))
```

So, if it doesn't find the `object` with the given `pk` it'll throw a 404.